# Upper bound for limsup

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Question - Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Then $\limsup(\frac{1+a_{n}}{a_{n}})^{n}\geq e$.

I don't know how to prove it. I can only think that I need to use that $\lim (\frac{n+1}{n})^{n}= e$.

Comment: is $\limsup(\frac{1+a_{n}}{a_{n}})^{a_n}\geq e$?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: maybe there is some other condition, please check the statement for the question

Comment: I edited. I changed the index.

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question now that you already got an answer to your original question!

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false, there is a counterexample:

Choose some number $c$ with $1<c<e$. and define $a_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{c} - 1}$.

Then 
$$\left(\frac{1+a_n}{a_n}  \right)^n = c < e$$

for all $n$.